# TFS failing to load during Visual Studio 2008 start up "Package Load Failure"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs

Error that pops up even before anything else loads:

```
Package Load Failure

Package 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ServicesHostPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamExplorer, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken = .... has failed to load properly
```

Restart has no effect

How can I fix this?

Comment: You could try reinstalling Team Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to cmd run `devenv /ResetSkipPkgs`

and or reinstall SP1, TF explorer

finally fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running devenv /resetsettings from the commandline prompt. If this does not help, please run devenv /log and see if it contains more meaningful error.

Comment: I did try reinstalling TFS explorer, it appeared to work, but I just had the error pop up again :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SP1 for VS installed?  If so, you'll need to re-apply it after installing Team Explorer (this was no longer a problem with VS 2010, as Team Explorer was installed with it by default).

If you have TFS (the server) also installed on the same machine, you'll need to make sure you either have SP1 for TFS and SP1 for VS installed or neither installed.  Having only one of the two service packs installed causes shared binaries to be mismatched, causing problems.

Comment: Michal's suggestion of running devenv /log is the next thing to try in order to hopefully get more info on what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with VS 2010. Reinstalling Team Explorer fixed my problem.

Here's the link to the download page: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=329

Here's direct link to the ISO:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/4/C/44CD7FE1-CA53-441C-863C-F7E78F24D092/VS2010TE1.iso